$\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy between embeddings of affine schemes
I know that $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy equivalence is not an equivalence relation on $Sch/k$ as the transitivity condition most often fails. I was wondering whether there existed a transitivity $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopy between three different embeddings $$f,g,h : \; \text{Spec}(k) \to \text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^3 - y^2)$$ Where the $f,g,h$ map respectively to the points $(0,0), (1,1) \text{ and } (1,-1)$.
Now I will give a few maps that I think should work, but I don't know whether they are genuine morphisms of schemes:
A homotopy between $f,g$ is given by a map $H: \text{Spec}(k) \times \mathbb{A}^1 \cong \mathbb{A^1}\to  \text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^3 -y^2))$ where the map maps $\alpha \in \mathbb{A}^1 $ to $H(\alpha) = (\alpha^2 , \alpha^3)$ and similarly a homotopy between $f,h$ is given by the map $G: \mathbb{A}^1 \to \text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^3 -y^2))$ such that $G(\alpha) \to (\alpha^2, -\alpha^3)$. One can check that indeed $H(0) = G(0) = f$ and $G(1) = h$ and $H(1) = g$. For the third homotopy from $h \text{ to } g$, I took the map $Z: \mathbb{A}^1 \to \text{Spec}(k[x,y]/(x^3 -y^2))$ such that $Z(\alpha) = ((2\alpha -1)^2, (2\alpha -1)^3)$ which should again have $Z(0) = h$ and $Z(1) = g$. My problem is as I mentioned above that I do not know whether the three maps I have given are morphisms of schemes, or in general checking whether given a map is a morphism of schemes.

You know that morphisms between affine schemes are just ring homomorphisms right?

Yes, but I do not know how I can translate a map $k[x,y]/(x^3 - y^2) \to k[t]$ to a map of schemes and visa versa.

Morphisms of affine schemes correspond to ring homomorphisms. But you have only described the morphisms here on $k$-valued points, which is not enough. But it can easily be generalized. Or we just write down the ring homomorphisms directly. Actually, these are $k$-algebra homomorphisms since we work with schemes over $k$.
For example, your map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to V(x^3-y^2)$ defined by $t \mapsto (t^2,-t^3)$ on $k$-valued points corresponds to the $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[X,Y]/\langle X^3-Y^2 \rangle \to k[T]$ mapping $[X] \mapsto T^2$ and $[Y] \mapsto -T^3$. Notice that this is well-defined since $(T^2)^3 - (-T^3)^2 = 0$.
In general, when you write down a polynomial map $V(I) \to V(J)$ between two varieties in the form $t \mapsto (p_1(t),\dotsc,p_n(t))$, where $t=t_1,\dotsc,t_m$ is a tuple of variables and $p_i$ are polynomials in these variables over $k$, then this corresponds to the $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]/J \to k[T_1,\dotsc,T_m]/I$, $[x_i] \mapsto [p_i(T)]$ (which is well-defined iff for all $q \in J$ we have $q(p_1,\dotsc,p_n) \in I$).
Another example which makes this clear hopefully: The morphism $V(X^2-Y^2) \to  V(UV)$ defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y,x-y)$ is coming from the $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[U,V]/\langle UV \rangle \to k[X,Y]/\langle X^2-Y^2 \rangle$ defined by $[U] \mapsto [X+Y]$, $[V] \mapsto [X-Y]$. When $2 \in k^{\times}$, it is an isomorphism (find the inverse in both forms!).
